# Proper way to delete triggers in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Short question...

Must one use the DROP TRIGGER operation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-droptrigger.html

Or would simply deleting entries from the pg_trigger table suffice?

Comment: When you can use standard SQL use it. Maybe tomorrow you will work with other RDBMS.

Comment: **Never** ever  mess around with the system tables. So, no: do not delete from `pg_trigger`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way is the only one. Use `drop trigger`, even if the deleting from `pg_trigger` seems to work fine. In fact it does not. After you manually delete an entry from `pg_trigger` you can get the error (not immediately but when you least expect it) like this:

> ERROR:  could not find tuple for trigger 123456

This is because of Postgres stores information about triggers on a table also in `pg_depend`. As an exemplary result, you will not be able to drop the table.

**Update.** Some explanations concerning dependencies between a trigger and its associated function.

It is not a trigger function that depends on a trigger, but vice versa, a trigger depends on a function. So if you want to drop a trigger and a trigger function at once you should drop the function with the option `cascade`, e.g.:

```
drop function a_trigger_function() cascade;
```

Without the option, you cannot drop a trigger function when a trigger exists (before a trigger was dropped). So statements in another answer to the question are misleading.

Note also that there are situations in which removing a function simultaneously with a trigger is not appropriate because a function may be used in many triggers.

Answer (score 3):

Do not delete from pg_trigger. Moreover you must explicitly delete the FUNCTION in which the trigger is based before deleting the trigger.

Comment: No, there is no such a compulsion. Of course, you should delete the trigger function if it will not be used.

Comment: @klin is there a way to delete the trigger function at the same time? Like `drop trigger xxx cascade`?

Comment: Thanks @klin, I wish I could upvote it a second time :)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you should use the `DROP TRIGGER` statement for that.
This is standard and portable.

Answer (score 2):

The trigger itself shouldn't be deleted. However, if it is deleted, the dependence will remain. The below query should clean up the mess.

```
DELETE FROM pg_depend d
WHERE d.classid = 'pg_trigger'::regclass
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_trigger WHERE oid = d.objid);
```